# Sysadmin and sa in sql server 2000 - drop and recreate login?

Tags: sql-server-2000, system-administration, sa

A somewhat open-ended question so any information that closes the gaps in my knowledge would be appreciated.

When doing a SQL Server upgrade from 2000 to 2008 the upgrade advisor can give the following warning:
The Upgrade Advisor detected one or more user-defined login names that match the names of fixed server roles. Fixed server role names are reserved in SQL Server 2008. Rename the login before upgrading to SQL Server 2008.

I believe this is because say for example a login of 'sysadmin' in a sql server 2000 database will clash with a fixed server role of 'sysadmin' in 2008..

Is there a way to safely drop and re-create these logins or could dropping a login of say 'sa' have unintended consequences?

Answer (score 0):

Repro of issue :

1) Delete the Builtin/administrator account .
2) Try to connect to SQL Server through sqlcmd or Management studio .You will  get the error 18456 Level 14 State 1.
3) Assume that i have forgotten the SA password as well.

Solution:
1) Login to the server using administrator account .

2) Stop SQL Server service and start it with -m switch(single user mode) .

2) Type sqlcmd -E and hit enter .If its named instance then sqlcmd -S  -E and hit enter.

4) You will see > sign

5) Commands you need to use

```
 CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\Administrators] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=  [master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]

go
```

6) Give sysadmin role to the login we just created

```
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'BUILTIN\Administrators', @rolename = N'sysadmin'


GO
```

7) You are done.Exit out of it .8) restart you SQL Server service without -m parameter.

You are done .Login again to SQL Server and reset the SA password .Save the SA password for the rainy day .

[Source](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/blogs/Abhay_c/sql-server-bi/454/recreating-builtin-administrator-account-in-sql-server-2000-and-above)